# Keeping deleted data for history or reuse

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, fluent-nhibernate

I'm working on a Card Management application in Asp.net Mvc. We are using Fluent Nhibernate as ORM and Sql Server 2008.

We are now considering to not really delete the data, when the user chooses to delete it.

My question is, what is the best way to do that and also what are the consequences of this(Performance, Db size)?

Some important tables of our database, may have thousands of records.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never thought this was a good idea, especially when foreign keys are involved. This can really make things more complex than they need to be. And I never liked the idea of records that are deleted but not really deleted. This is just messy, IMO.

If you want to keep deleted rows around, I would suggest putting them in an archive or history table of some sort. That way you have them there for future analysis, if you need to, and can bring them back later, if necessary.

The size of your database really isn't an issue. "Thousands" of records is nothing for SQL Server. In our manufacturing database, we have hundreds of millions of rows in some of our tables. Performance is excellent.

With SQL Server 2008, you have [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx) available to you, which can, very nicely, handle deleted rows for you.

Comment: Hi Randy Minder, Is your first suggestion, (putting data in an archive or history table) the same as using the Sql Server 'Change Data Capture' ?

Comment: @Djaved - Essentially yes. Using CDC is one way of getting deleted rows in to an archive (history) table.

Comment: You could also take a look at Envers, an NHibernate extension, that tracks revision information of your entities (deleted records, too). Just mark your entities as audited with attributes or use the fluent interface to activate automatic auditing in separate history tables. It works with every database, just like NHibernate does. You can find it [here](https://bitbucket.org/RogerKratz/nhibernate.envers).

Answer (score 2):

Where I work now and at previous positions the idea has always been geared around a `DeletedDate` and `DeletedBy` on records. That way whenever you retrieve information, you can just filter out and only get records where `DeletedDate == null`.

This way also gives you a way of tracking who deleted the data and when, whilst also giving you the ability to "revert" the deletion by resetting the `DeletedDate` to null.

In terms of performance and database size I wouldn't worry about it too much as SQL Server is more than capable of coping with millions of rows of data.

If performance is absolutely critical and you notice the application getting slower, you can easily enough archive off the deleted data into a separate backed up database.

If you're not bothered about keeping the data for too long, you could periodically delete everything in the database that has a `DeletedDate` of over a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

I would make after delete trigger (it also has some performance penalty) and insert deleted rows in archive table. Then its possible to partition/data compress that archive table (if using enterprice version of SQL Server).

Archive table would look just like base table, except have some additional ID column and i would also put deletion date and user name who deleted data.

Comment: Hi Janis, what do you mean by 'partition/data compress' ? can you send me a example of that? thanks